# Error al utilizar el server de Atom para una App de React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, atom-editor

> ./src/index.css
>   (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css) C:\Users\user\esta-app\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\grid-template.js:1
>
> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
>                                                                  SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

He visto por ahi que es un problema con un **loader de css**...pero no estoy muy seguro ya que esos errores eran previos a la creacion del workbox-webpack-plugin.

También desahibilite el tema de `serviceWorker.unregister()`

Ayuda y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, como soy nuevo en crear aplicaciones nativas a traves de React.js.

Hay dos cosas que hice mal.

1. Debemos asegurarnos que el proceso de instalación de los archivos este bien...Cuando entre al archivo **grid-template.js**, no habia ningún metodo adentro. Por lo tanto no podia ejecutar sus funciones a la hora de usar el web-server.
2. Tambien soy nuevo en esto de **Node.js** que es clave para poder hacer el build en react, y los comandos que confundo son **npx** y **npm**. Uno es para utilizar los modulos que tienes localmente y el otro es para hacer uso de estos mismos sin tener que instalarlos globalmente en tu computadora, asi como las variables de entorno. Esas cosas...